# Why MATLAB's imclose and Opencv Python's MORPH_CLOSE show different outputs?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, code-translation

I was trying to convert some MATLAB codes to Python codes which are related to some image-processing.

When I did `imclose` in MATLAB with a disc shape of 7, the hole in the original binary image was filled and it looks good. But when I did `MORPH_CLOSE` with an ellipse of kernel size 7 to the same binary image, the hole didn't close. Why did it happen?

This is the MATLAB code:

```
cmask = imread('image.jpeg');
cm = imclose(im2bw(cmask),strel('disk',7));
```

This is my Python code corresponding to above MATLAB code:

```
import cv2 as cv
cmask=cv.imread('image.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(cmask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_,bwcmask = cv2.threshold(gray, 127,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel_7=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(7,7))
cm = cv2.morphologyEx(bwcmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_7)
```

This is my input image:

[image: This is my input image]

This is my MATLAB output image:

[image: This is my MATLAB output image]

This is my Python output image:

[image: This is my python output image]

This is the output image with kernel size 11 in python

[image: This is the output image with kernel size 11 in python]

Why is the output different in MATLAB and Python even steps are the same? I want an output image with no holes from Python code (without altering the shape of my object). Kernel size more than 10 could close the hole but it alters my original image shape.

Comment: One may be using diameter and the other radius for the structuring element?

Comment: Yes, in Matlab/Octave 7 is radius (15x15 kernel), in OpenCV (7,7) is  size kernel (diameter).

Comment: @AlexAlex but kernel size above 10 is changing my input image's shape.

Comment: It looks like OpenCV uses a different boundary extension than MATLAB by default. Set the `borderValue` parameter to 0.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks man it's helpful.