# Why does imclose(Image,nhood) in MATLAB give different output than MORP.CLOSE in OpenCV?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I am trying to convert some MATLAB code to Python, related to image-processing.

When I did

```matlab
% matlab R2017a
nhood = true(5);     % will give 5x5 matrix containing 1s size 5x5
J = imclose(Image,nhood);
```

in MATLAB, the result is different than when I did

```py
import cv2 as cv
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)  # will give result like true(5)
J = cv.morphologyEx(Image,cv.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)
```

in Python.

This is the result of MATLAB:

[image: MATLAB results]

And this is for the Python:

[image: Python results]

The difference is 210 pixels, see below. The red circle shows the pixels that exist in Python with 1 value but not in the MATLAB.

[image: the difference results]

Sorry if it’s so small, my image size is 2048x2048 and have values 0 and 1, and the error just 210 pixels.

When I use another library such as `skimage.morphology.closing` and `mahotas.close` with the same parameter, it will give me the same result as `MORPH.CLOSE`.

What I want to ask is:

1. Am I using the wrong parameter in Python like the `kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)`?
2. If not, is there any library that will give me the same exact result like `imclose()` MATLAB?
3. Which of the MATLAB and Python results is correct?

I already looked at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112076/why-matlabs-imclose-and-opencv-pythons-morph-close-show-different-outputs). When I use `borderValue = 0` in `MORPH.CLOSE`, my result will give me error 2115 pixels that contain 1 value in MATLAB but not in the Python.

[ UPDATE ]

1. the input image is [Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MsWR.png)
2. the cropped of the difference pixels is [cropped difference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsveR.png)
3. So for the difference pixels image, it turns out that the pixels are not only in that position but scattered in several positions. You can see it here [image: more specific image of difference pixels]

And if seen from the results, the location of the pixel error coincides at the ends of the row or column of the matrix.
I hope it can make more hints for this question.

4. This is the program in MATLAB that i use to check the error,

```matlab
mask = zeros(2048,2048); %inisialisasi error matrix  
error = 0;
for x = 1:size(J_Matlab,1)
    for y = 1:size(J_Matlab,2)
        if J_Matlab(x,y)== J_Python(x,y)
            mask(x,y) = 0; % no differences
        else
            mask(x,y) = 1;
            error = error + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

so i load the Python data into MATLAB, then i compare it in with the MATLAB data. And if you want to check the data that i use for the input in closing function, you can look it in the comment section ( in drive link )

5. so for this problem, my teacher said that it was ok to use either MATLAB or Python program because the error is not significant. but if i found the solution, i will post it here ASAP. Thanks for the instruction, suggestions, and critics for my first post.

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: ok thanks, sorry if im wrong. im new in this forum

Comment: What is the input image?

Comment: i give the link of the image in the question above, sorry I don't know how to add link of the image in this comment section @CrisLuengo

Comment: The image is too large, it's getting downscaled. Try cropping the lower-right corner of the image, where the difference appears, and using that as the example image. If it's small enough, it will not get downscaled when uploading here. Make sure you still see the difference when using the cropped image!

Comment: ok, thanks for the recommendations, i will give the new link of the cropped image in the question

Comment: I can still not reproduce your issue because I still don’t have an input image I can apply the closing on. The input image you have here is downscaled. Post a smaller image that I (or anyone else) can use to reproduce this issue.

Comment: ok sorry for the long answer, here I give a gdrive link for .mat and .npy data so you can try it in MATLAB or Python. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1roRn3Bx4wkjHrg3sWPgqAqE1eGpk7OX9?usp=sharing